# const char* const* p param compiled in g++ but not gcc

Tags: c++, c, function, parameter-passing

I have the following program that compiles fine in g++ but not in gcc.

g() takes a pointer to an array of char*, and should not modify anything that p points to.

Anyway to make this work properly in C?

```
% cat t.c
void g(const char* const* p) {}
int main()
{
  char** p = 0;
  g(p);  
}

% g++ t.c
% gcc t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:5:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘g’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   g(p);
     ^
t.c:1:6: note: expected ‘const char * const*’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
 void g(const char* const* p) {}
      ^
%
```

Comment: `C++` and `C` are different languages. In C `*const` makes it incompatible in nested pointer type.

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you every thing you need to know. Make p as the same signature as the argument of g.

```
    const char* const* p = 0;
```

But if you need whatever p is pointing to to be a readonly then this type specification is enough for the assignment of p and g argument (although it will be possible to change whatever the array is pointing to):

```
    char* const* p = 0;
```

Comment: In other words, I need to cast in C, but not in C++.

Comment: @cktan yes you can cast p when call g and leave p declaration as it is.

Answer (score 2):

##### Situation in C

In C qualifiers are only allowed to be implicitly added for the top-most pointer level:

**6.3.2.3 Pointers**

> <sup>2</sup> For any qualifier q, a pointer to a non-q-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to
> the q-qualified version of the type; the values stored in the original and converted pointers
> shall compare equal.

So you can only add const to the top-most pointer implicitly, e.g.:

```c
char** p = 0;
char* const* other = p; // ok

const char** other = p; // not ok: adding const not at top-level
```

The reasoning for this is that it would allow you to get a non-const pointer to a const value if you jump through a few hoops:

```c
const char c = 'C';
char* ptr;
const char **ptrPtr = &ptr; // this is not legal
*ptrPtr = &c;
```

At first glance that piece of code looks reasonable - you have `ptrPtr` that points to `ptr` that points to `c`.
The problem is that you can modify `c` through `ptr` now (which is **not** const-qualified), e.g.:

```c
*ptr = 'X'; // will change c
```

[Here's an FAQ entry about this](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html) if you want to read a bit more about it.

---

You can still force it though if you want with an explicit cast:

```c
void g(const char* const* p) {}

int main()
{
  char** p = 0;
  g((const char* const*)p); 
}
```

##### Situation in C++

C++ is a bit more lenient in how much constness can implicitly be added.

[**7.3.6 Qualification conversions**](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual)

> <sup>(1)</sup>A qualification-decomposition of a type T is a sequence of
> cv<sub>i</sub> and P<sub>i</sub> such that T is
>         “cv<sub>0</sub> P<sub>0</sub> cv<sub>1</sub> P<sub>1</sub> ⋯ cv<sub>n-1</sub> P<sub>n−1</sub> cv<sub>n</sub> U” for n ≥ 0,
> where each cv<sub>i</sub> is a set of cv-qualifiers ([basic.type.qualifier]), and each P<sub>i</sub> is “pointer to” ([dcl.ptr]), “pointer to member of class C<sub>i</sub> of type” ([dcl.mptr]), “array of N<sub>i</sub>”, or “array of unknown bound of” ([dcl.array]). If P<sub>i</sub> designates an array, the cv-qualifiers cv<sub>i+1</sub> on the element type are also taken as the cv-qualifiers cv<sub>i</sub> of the array.
>
> <sup>(2)</sup> Two types T1 and T2 are similar if they have qualification-decompositions with the same n such that corresponding P<sub>i</sub> components are either the same or one is “array of N<sub>i</sub>” and the other is “array of unknown bound of”, and the types denoted by U are the same.
>
> <sup>(3)</sup> The qualification-combined type of two types T1 and T2 is the type T3 similar to T1 whose qualification-decomposition is such that:
>
> - <sup>(3.1)</sup> for every i > 0, cv<sup>3</sup><sub>i</sub> is the union of cv<sup>1</sup><sub>i</sub> and cv<sup>2</sup><sub>i</sub>,
> - <sup>(3.2)</sup> if either P<sup>1</sup><sub>i</sub> or P<sup>2</sup><sub>i</sub> is “array of unknown bound of”, P<sup>3</sup><sub>i</sub> is “array of unknown bound of”, otherwise it is P<sup>1</sup><sub>i</sub>, and
> - <sup>(3.3)</sup> if the resulting cv<sup>3</sup><sub>i</sub> is different from cv<sup>1</sup><sub>i</sub> or cv<sup>2</sup><sub>i</sub>, or the resulting P<sup>3</sup><sub>i</sub> is different from P<sup>1</sup><sub>i</sub> or P<sup>2</sup><sub>i</sub>, then const is added to every cv<sup>3</sup><sub>k</sub> for 0 < k < i,
>
> where cv<sup>j</sup><sub>i</sub> and P<sup>j</sup><sub>i</sub> are the components of the qualification-decomposition of T*j*.

Which essentially just boils down just to:

- you can always add const to the top level
- if you add const to a lower level, all levels up from that level must also be const

this "const-propagation" is necessary to avoid exactly that edge-case that is present in C: getting a non-const pointer to a const object.

a few examples: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/oj4EEdod6)

```cpp
    int i = 1;
    int* ip = &i;
    int** ipp = &ip;
    int*** ippp = &ipp;

    const int* t1 = ip; // ok
    const int* const* t2 = ipp; // ok
    const int* const* const* t3 = ippp; // ok

    // const int** t4 = ipp; // not ok
    // const int*** t5 = ippp; // not ok
    // const int* const** t6 = ippp; // not ok

    int* const* t7 = ipp; // ok
    int* const* const* t8 = ippp; // ok

    // int* const** t9 = ippp; // not ok
}
```

---

##### Conclusion

So that is the reason why your code compiles with g++ but not with gcc:

C++ allows you to add const-qualifiers for multiple pointer levels implicitly (as long as you follow da rules outlined above), while C only allows you to add const to the top-level pointer implicitly.